# Find if a Substring is Part of List/Array Directly

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, substring

I've a list defined as:

```
List<string> content = new List<string>(){ "Hello This", "This is", "This" };
```

I want a code to find if the list contains the Keyword This, and if yes get its first occurrence.

*Existing Code :*

```
foreach(string line in content){
     if(line.Contains("This"))
          return line;
}
```

I want to simply and know if some other alternative is there. If we know the complete string then we could use List.Contains, but for a substring, how to proceed?

USING .NET 2.0. Please suggest without using LINQ.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @DGibbs nothing is wrong but I wanted to know if there's something more simple/direct I could be using instead of this.

Comment: @B V Raman It looks perfectly simple to me. If I couldn't use LINQ, that's how I'd do it. Only thing I'd suggest is making sure you're doing a case-insensitive comparison/contains

Comment: I think this is already the simplest solution without LINQ.

Comment: Which version of C#? Multiple answers use lambda expressions, but those didn't exist prior to C# 3, which was introduced after .NET 2.0.

Comment: @BVRaman Please look my answer too, i have simplified that too lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you were searching for in C#2.0 :

```
List<string> content = new List<string>() { "Hello This", "This is", "This" };
string keyword = "This";
string element = content.Find(delegate(string s) { return s.Contains(keyword); });
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx), `FindIndex` is available since `Framework 2.0` and can be used for your problem.

`FindIndex` searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List.

```
List<string> content = new List<string>() { "Hello This", "This is", "This" };
var index = content.FindIndex(p => p.Contains("This"));
if (index >= 0)
    return content[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Find()` The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified
>   predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Find()** is available from `NET Framework 2.0`

```
 List<string> content = new List<string>() { "Hello This", "This is", "This" };
 string firstOccurance = content.Find(g => g.Contains("This"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use linq, this will do the same as your for loop:

```
return content.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("This"));
```

Comment: He will want FirstOrDefault as he doesn't know the list contains the item he is searching for...

Comment: Thanks, but any approach without LINQ since I'm on .NET 2.0

Comment: Carra - its linq "FirstOrDefault" and "Contains".